# closure of open set in topological space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry

How to prove : If $X$ is a topological space, $U$ is open in $X$, and $A$ is dense in $X$, then $\overline{U}=\overline{U \cap A}$

Comment: I admit this exercise follows pretty straightforwardly from the definitions... I didn't think much. Go through the steps, tell me where you got stuck ; perhaps I could help and give tips for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\overline U = \underset{ \mathcal F \text{ closed}}{ \bigcap_{U \subseteq \mathcal F} }\mathcal F, \quad \overline {U \cap A}  = \underset{ \mathcal F \text{ closed}}{ \bigcap_{U \cap A \subseteq \mathcal F} }\mathcal F, 
$$
so to see that $(\subseteq)$ and $(\supseteq)$ holds, it suffices to see that $U \subseteq \mathcal F$ if and only if $U \cap A \subseteq \mathcal F$ when $\mathcal F$ is closed, $U$ is open and $A$ is dense in $X$. One direction is clear because $U \cap A \subseteq U$. For the other one, note that if $U \cap A \subseteq \mathcal F$, then $A \subseteq \mathcal F \cup U^c$, and since $U$ is open, $\mathcal F \cup U^c$ is closed, hence $X = \overline A \subseteq \mathcal F \cup U^c$ and $\mathcal F \cup U^c = X$, which means $U \cap \mathcal F^c = \varnothing$, thus $U \subseteq \mathcal F$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: if $U \cap A \subset \mathcal{F}$ why is $A \subset \mathcal{F} \cup U^c$ ?

Comment: @chandu1729, if $U \cap A \subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}^c \subset (U \cap A)^c = U^c \cup A^c$. Suppose that $x \in A$ and $x \not\in \mathcal{F}$. Then $x \not\in A^c, x\in \mathcal{F}^c$. So $x \in U^c$.

Comment: @chandu : LJR has the right mathematical explanation, but if you want to "guess" those identities better, go this way : take $x \in A$. If $x \in U$, then $x \in \mathcal F$, and if $x \notin U$, well. So $x \in \mathcal F \cup U^c$ and $A \subseteq \mathcal F \cup U^c$. That's usually my technique to switch those inclusions around.

Comment: @LJR : if you were to work it out with set inclusions, do it all the way! You have $\mathcal F^c \subseteq U^c \cup A^c$, hence $\mathcal F^c \cap U \subseteq (U^c \cup A^c) \cap U = A^c \cap U \subseteq A^c$, which means $A \subseteq (\mathcal F^c \cap U)^c = U^c \cup \mathcal F$. As you can see it is pretty painful ; better off starting with elements.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different demonstration (though easily translatable into/from Patrick Da Silva's answer) of this fact is as follows:

> First note that as $U \cap A \subseteq U$ then $\overline{U \cap A} \subseteq \overline{U}$, so we need only show the reverse inclusion.  Take any $x \in \overline{U}$.  To show that $x \in \overline{U \cap A}$ we need only show that $V \cap ( U \cap A ) \neq \emptyset$ for every open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$.  Given an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, since $x \in \overline{U}$, then $V \cap U \neq \emptyset$. But $V \cap U$ is an open set, now known to be nonempty, and since $A$ is dense we must have $V \cap ( U \cap A ) = ( V \cap U ) \cap A \neq \emptyset$.  It thus follows that $x \in \overline{ U \cap A }$, and so $\overline{U} \subseteq \overline{U \cap A}$.

Comment: Yeah it's the same proof. You only used the result that $x \in \overline U$ if and only if for every open set $A \ni x$, $A \cap U \neq \varnothing$, but then you use the 'same steps'. Perhaps it can be easier to think of this one than mine... but the right way to see our two answers is that you thought in terms of open sets while I thought in terms of closed sets. Of course our proofs are similar.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I was nearly certain the two answers were "spiritual partners" though hadn't yet had enough coffee to be 100% sure.

Comment: Coffee's a powerful weapon, is it! My weapon is tea, I get hit less hard with recoil!